# what is the function of unzip-native?

Tags: yocto, openembedded

In a yocto bb, I see this:

```
DEPENDS += "unzip-native"
```

I can't find an introduction in:
https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html

What's the purpose to add this?

Comment: The recipe depends on `unzip` native on the HOST  compilation computer, and not on TARGET(Embedded Board).

Answer (score 0):

The recipe, presumably, uses unzip to unpack archives at some point.